# Подключение к базе данных sql через php

Tags: php, sql

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных с помощью этого скрипта

```
<?php 
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';
$dblink = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, 'db');
if($dblink)
echo 'Соединение установлено.';
else
die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');
if($dblink)
echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
else
die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$result=mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM `pisos`');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo $row['group_number'];
}
?>
```

PHP7.0 выдаёт ошибку:

```
Соединение установлено. Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/admin/data/www/site/connect.php on line 15
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/admin/data/www/site/connect.php on line 16
```

Что этому дьяволу от меня нужно и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка достаточно описательная.

Функция `mysqli_query` принимает 2 параметра, а вы передаете только 1 ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)), например: `mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT * FROM pisos')`